# Why using a createSelector function in another file causes re-render vs creating "inline", both with useMemo

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have this app that I'm working on that is using RTK and in the documentation for selecting values from results, in queries using RTK Query, they have an example with a createSelector and React.useMemo. Here's that code and the [page](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-values-from-results)

```js
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { selectUserById } from '../users/usersSlice'
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../api/apiSlice'

export const UserPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { userId } = match.params

  const user = useSelector(state => selectUserById(state, userId))

  const selectPostsForUser = useMemo(() => {
    const emptyArray = []
    // Return a unique selector instance for this page so that
    // the filtered results are correctly memoized
    return createSelector(
      res => res.data,
      (res, userId) => userId,
      (data, userId) => data?.filter(post => post.user === userId) ?? emptyArray
    )
  }, [])

  // Use the same posts query, but extract only part of its data
  const { postsForUser } = useGetPostsQuery(undefined, {
    selectFromResult: result => ({
      // We can optionally include the other metadata fields from the result here
      ...result,
      // Include a field called `postsForUser` in the hook result object,
      // which will be a filtered list of posts
      postsForUser: selectPostsForUser(result, userId)
    })
  })

  // omit rendering logic
}
```

So I did the same in my app, but I thought that if it's using the createSelector then it can be in a separate slice file. So I have this code in a slice file:

```js
export const selectFoo = createSelector(
  [
    (result: { data?: TypeOne[] }) => result.data,
    (result: { data?: TypeOne[] }, status: TypeTwo) => status,
  ],
  (data: TypeOne[] | undefined, status) => {
    return data?.filter((d) => d.status === status) ?? [];
  }
);
```

Then I created a hook that uses this selector so that I can just pass in a status value and get the filtered results. This is in another file as well.

```js
function useGetFooByStatus(status: WebBookmkarkStatus) {
  const selectFooMemoized = useMemo(() => {
      return selectFoo;
  }, []);

  const { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError } =
    useGetFoosQuery(
      "key",
      {
        selectFromResult: (result) => ({
          isError: result.isError,
          isFetching: result.isFetching,
          isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
          isLoading: result.isLoading,
          error: result.error,
          foos: selectFooMemoized(result, status),
        }),
      }
    );

  return { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError };
}
```

Then lastly I'm using this hook in several places in the app.

The problem then is when I'm causing a re-render in another part of the app causes the query hook to run again (I think), but the selector function runs again, not returning the memoized value, even though nothing has changed. I haven't really figured it out what causes the re-render in another part of the app, but when I do the following step, it stops re-rendering.

If I replace the selector function in the `useGetFooByStatus` with the same one in the slice file. With this, the value is memoized correctly.

(Just to remove any doubt, the hook would look like this)

```js
function useGetFooByStatus(status: TypeTwo) {
  const selectFooMemoized = useMemo(() => {
      return createSelector(
      [
        (result: { data?: TypeOne[] }) => result.data,
        (result: { data?: TypeOne[] }, status: TypeTwo) =>
          status,
      ],
      (data: TypeOne[] | undefined, status) =>
        data?.filter((d) => d.status === status) ?? []
    );
  }, []);

  const { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError } =
    useGetFoosQuery(
      "key",
      {
        selectFromResult: (result) => ({
          isError: result.isError,
          isFetching: result.isFetching,
          isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
          isLoading: result.isLoading,
          error: result.error,
          foos: selectFooMemoized(result, status),
        }),
      }
    );

  return { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError };
}
```

Sorry for the long question, just want to try and explain everything :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 has one selector used for your whole app. That selector has a cache size of 1, so if you call it always with the same argument it will not recalculate, but if you call it with `1` and then with `2` and then with `1` and then with `2` it will always recalculate in-between and always return a different (new object) as a result.

Solution 2 creates one such selector per component instance.

Now imagine two different components calling these selectors - with two different queries with two different results.

Solution 1 will flip-flop and always create a new result - solution 2 will stay stable "per-component" and not cause rerenders.

Comment: Is there a way for me to test or verify that the variables in the input selectors are different from the last time run?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work:

```
const EMPTY = [];
const createSelectFoo = (status: TypeTwo) => createSelector(
  [
    (result: { data?: TypeOne[] }) => result.data,
  ],
  (data: TypeOne[] | undefined) => {
    return data?.filter((d) => d.status === status) ? EMPTY;
  }
);


function useGetFooByStatus(status: TypeTwo) {
  //only create selector if status changes, this will
  //  memoize the result when multiple components
  //  call this hook with different status in one render
  //  cycle
  const selectFooMemoized = useMemo(() => {
    return createSelectFoo(status);
  }, [status]);  
  const { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError } =
    useGetFoosQuery(
      "key",
      {
        selectFromResult: (result) => ({
          isError: result.isError,
          isFetching: result.isFetching,
          isSuccess: result.isSuccess,
          isLoading: result.isLoading,
          error: result.error,
          foos: selectFooMemoized(result),
        }),
      }
    );

  return { foos, isFetching, isSuccess, isError };
}
```

You may want to make your component a pure component with React.memo, some more information with examples of selectors can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Comment: This is basically the same as creating it inline right? I like this approach a lot more than having to create it inline all the time haha

Comment: @LoyalPotato Looking at it more closely you may be right, both end up with a component having its own selector and both should in theory not re render as long as status does not change. Maybe it is because [strictmode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) or something else is causing the re renders. Is it possible to create a minimal example reproducing this issue?

Comment: The strict mode re render is still shown in the console log (but greyed out), so I know the extra renders is caused by that.
My guess would be something to do with RTK Queries and re processing the results on re fetching (either cache or request).
And right now I can't create something, but later in the day I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: PS: This fixed my issue with the re renders, just wanted to know now what caused it, but I think the answer from phry tackles that.

Comment: @LoyalPotato Nice to hear it's fixed. The link explains why a shared parameterised selector isn't memoized [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-and-memoized)

Comment: The solution that is shown in the link you mentioned is the one I was already using. The issue was that the function was still being run even with memoization.
Changing so that it creates a selector instance based on the status, fixed that ( I think. correct me if I'm wrong as I'm still partially guessing :))